# Why can't I have "public static const string S = "stuff"; in my Class?

Tags: c#, constants

When trying to compile my class I get an error:

> The constant `'NamespaceName.ClassName.CONST_NAME'` cannot be marked static.

at the line:

```
public static const string CONST_NAME = "blah";
```

I could do this all of the time in Java.  What am I doing wrong?  And why doesn't it let me do this?

Comment: Good question. Why do we have to learn it the hard way ? The compiler should just ignore the static  and display a warning so that we know (why) we could avoid typing some chars the next time.

Answer (score 778, accepted):

A `const` object is always `static`.

Comment: const makes the variable constant and cannot be changed.

Comment: @jinguy: const inherently means static -- if you have any const, it's already static, and static therefore does not need to be nor cannot be specified.

Comment: I don't think C# has a direct analog to "final"

Comment: The only equivalent would be readonly, but it's not quite the same.

Comment: ... at least in this context, I should add.  You can mark a class 'sealed' to prevent inheritance.

Comment: The more C# I write, the more I realize I'm a Java fanboi.

Comment: @jjnguy: Why? readonly is actually more flexible than Java's final for variables - you can set it as many times as you like in the constructor, but not elsewhere. That can be very handy.

Comment: Consts are inlined at compile time and are not present in the static type object at runtime.  Statics aren't inlined and live inside the type object.  I add this just because nobody's mentioned the difference...

Comment: They're still present at execution time - you can get at them with reflection, for example (with GetField).

Comment: Jon, please make the next C# allows const static readonly all on one and that they don't come up with this "foo implies bar so foo bar is invalid" stuff. it annoyed me all day long when i programmed with c# in school

Comment: @litb: Wow, I wish I had that sort of influence ;) I wouldn't use it for that though - I have no problem with disallowing redundancy. (It's like putting "public" on interface members. Ugh.) There are plenty of more important things to change in C#. Readonly autoproperties would be my first choice...

Comment: I don't hate C# I guess...I'll just use readonly I guess.....thanks for all of the good info!

Comment: Nomatter what, I think that it is wrong to handle the definition of public static const as an error. Since const implies static, the compiler can just ignore the static definition, or give a warning(e.g. 'static definition of const is redundant at line 123').

Comment: It redundantly repeats again repetitively.

Comment: static const would be useful in switch expressions, but because they can't be declared this is not possible.

Answer (score 124):

From the [C# language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) *(PDF page 287 - or 300th page of the PDF):*

> Even though constants are considered
>   static members, a constant
>   declaration neither requires nor
>   allows a static modifier.

Comment: Also available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645749(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 39):

A const member is considered static by the compiler, as well as implying constant value semantics, which means references to the constant might be compiled into the using code as the value of the constant member, instead of a reference to the member.

In other words, a const member containing the value 10, might get compiled into code that uses it as the number 10, instead of a reference to the const member.

This is different from a static readonly field, which will always be compiled as a reference to the field.

Note, this is pre-JIT. When the JIT'ter comes into play, it might compile both these into the target code as values.

Comment: Very important point, that the compiled code presumes the constant value will not change in a future version.

Answer (score 8):

C#'s `const` is the exact same thing as Java's `final`, except it's absolutely always `static`. In my opinion, it's not really necessary for a `const` variable to be non-`static`, but if you need to access a `const` variable non-`static`-ly, you can do:

```
class MyClass
{    
    private const int myLowercase_Private_Const_Int = 0;
    public const int MyUppercase_Public_Const_Int = 0;

    /*        
      You can have the `private const int` lowercase 
      and the `public int` Uppercase:
    */
    public int MyLowercase_Private_Const_Int
    {
        get
        {
            return MyClass.myLowercase_Private_Const_Int;
        }
    }  

    /*
      Or you can have the `public const int` uppercase 
      and the `public int` slighly altered
      (i.e. an underscore preceding the name):
    */
    public int _MyUppercase_Public_Const_Int
    {
        get
        {
            return MyClass.MyUppercase_Public_Const_Int;
        }
    } 

    /*
      Or you can have the `public const int` uppercase 
      and get the `public int` with a 'Get' method:
    */
    public int Get_MyUppercase_Public_Const_Int()
    {
        return MyClass.MyUppercase_Public_Const_Int;
    }    
}
```

Well, now I realize this question was asked 4 years ago, but since I put around 2 hours of work, consisting of trying all sorts of different ways of answering and code formatting,  into this answer, I'm still posting it. :)

But, for the record, I still feel kinda silly.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Java `final` behaves exactly like C# `readonly`, and not like `const` at all.

Comment: @jjnguy Thanks for the edit; I don't really know why I chose that original wording.

Answer (score 7):

From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx

... Also, while **a const field is a compile-time constant**, the readonly field can be used for runtime constants...

So using static in const fields is like trying to make a defined (with #define) static in C/C++... Since it is replaced with its value in compile-time of course it is initiated once for all instances (=static).

Answer (score 3):

const is similar to static we can access both varables with class name but diff is  static variables can be modified and const can not.