# Static Constants in C#

Tags: c#, string, constants

I have this code;

```
using System;

namespace Rapido
{
    class Constants
    {
        public static const string FrameworkName = "Rapido Framework";
    }  
}
```

Visual Studio tells me: `The constant 'Rapido.Constants.FrameworkName' cannot be marked static`

How can I make this constant available from other classes without having to create a new instance of it? (ie. directly accessing it via `Rapido.Constants.FrameworkName`)

Comment: Related post - [Why can't I have “public static const string S = ”stuff"; in my Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/408192/465053)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string FrameworkName = "Rapido Framework";
}
```

Comment: The poster asked for a way of not instantiating a class, and have it contain constants.

Comment: You wouldn't have to create an instance to get to the constant value.  Constants work just like statics.  Other than they are copied at compile time instead of referenced.

Comment: would the downvoter (19/05/2011) plase leave a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I assume it's because the solution does not explain itself.

Comment: If that doesn't explain the question "How can I make this constant available from other classes without having to create a new instance of it?" - then I humbly suggest one shouldn't be programming in c#

Answer (score 38):

A const is already static as it cannot change between instances.

Comment: Right... so I don't understand why the compiler balks when you explicitly denote it as such...

Comment: I understand that's the way it's implemented.  I'm asking why it's done that way.

Comment: Take care not to confuse const and static, they mean different things. const refers to an item's value whereas static refers to how an items storage is allocated. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842609/why-does-c-not-allow-const-and-static-on-the-same-line/842649#842649

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to declare it as static - public const string is enough.

Comment: In fact it is an error to declare it static because that would imply that memory allocation and runtime initialisation needs to take place, neither of which is needed for a constant.