# C# What is the difference between static and constant?

Tags: c#, variables, static, constants

As it says. I am about to define a constant, or static, value in a program I am writing and am confused as to why you would use one or the other. As [the only related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842590/static-constants-in-c) i get when asking this question deals with someone who wants to mark something as both static and constant at once I suspect I am not the only person a bit lost with these concepts.

So why would I use static and why would I use constant? What's the distinction? Are they synonymous? If so, that's cool, but if not why not? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`const` is dealt with at compile time. Every reference to that constant is replaced by the constant value.

`static` is very different. It is a variable which exists only once but belongs to all objects of that type. It can be edited unless marked as `readonly` (or given a getter but no setter). If it is marked as `readonly` then it is essentially a constant, but it is handled at runtime, not by the compiler.

Answer (score 5):

First off, they are **not** synonymous.

- [`static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) marks a member as belonging to the *type*.
- [`const`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) means the member *value* cannot be changed. The value is determined at compile time and substituted wherever it appears.

For better understanding of how `static` is to be used, read [`Static Classes and Static Members`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).

Comment: When used with a class member, `const` does imply `static`, though.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi - and yet, a `static` member value _can_ change.

Answer (score 1):

And wouldn't you know it five minutes later I find [this](http://devlicio.us/blogs/joe_niland/archive/2006/09/27/C_2300_-static-readonly-vs-constant-variables_3A00_-when-to-use-each.aspx).

Any other comments?

Comment: @Saif al Harthi: "Wouldn't you know it" is simply an expression of surprise.

Comment: Modify your question to include "static readonly", include short summary of the article here and I can up vote your answer.