# My implementation of global CONSTs - is it possible to do something differently?

Tags: c#

I'm a professional php programmer and lately I started a project in C#.
These are my first steps with C#.

For one of my solutions I would like to use global CONSTs. I'm aware that C# doesn't allow you to define any variable outside a class scope, but I would like to try and implement something like it anyway, even just for the purpose of learning different techniques in the language.

I see the best way to do something similar global CONSTs is to define a static class, let's call it Const, that will hold my all of my solution's 'constants'.
The class will use a private dictionary to hold the values, a method called 'define()' to set a value in this dictionar, 'is_defined()' to check if a const exists etc..

Now I'm about to write the method that will return the value.
Obviously I could use a method *Const.GetConst('someConstName')* and get the wanted value, but that's a long way to retrieve a const anytime I need it. 
I though of using something like PHP's magic getter (if you're not familiar with it - you define inside a class a method called '__get' which handles all requests for a variable inside the class which is not defined).
However, I couldn't find anything similar in C#. The closest thing I could find is a way to dynamically create a method inside a class in runtime, so that everytime a CONST will be created in my class, I'll create a "get method" that will pull the value from the private dictionary (this is not a get method in the classic form because is won't return a variable, instead, it will look for a value in a dictionary and return it).

Basically, what I'm asking is - 
- Is there any way to define global consts?
- (even id the answer to the previous question is yes) Is there a way to set a better getter for dynamically define variables?

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: something like this? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842590/static-constants-in-c/842596#842596

Comment: I think you're still something too much in the PHP 'mood'. Why do you use a dictionary to store variables when you know when you want to use them? You can think of a name on beforehand, and stuff them in the appropriate class, like `Database.ConnectionString`, with all benefits of encapsulation, strong typing, et cetera.

Comment: If they're dynamic properties _and_ values, what exactly is constant about them? You have two different scenarios here: exposure of constants _or_ a property bag; but they're are two different things.

Answer (score 4):

C# certainly allows you to declare public constants, Math.Pi would be a good example.  It is however almost always the wrong thing to do.  The problem is that constant values are directly compiled into the IL.  That makes them *very* efficient, no memory access is required to lookup their value, but also *very* dangerous when you make the public.

What goes wrong is deploying updates for the assembly that contains the const declaration.  You can alter the value but *other* assemblies that also use the constant are still using the old value.  Embedded firmly in their IL.  This will not come to a good end.

Public constants are only suitable for manifest constants.  Like Math.Pi, it takes a drastic change in the way the Universe works to ever change that value.  Something like a company or product name is already suspect, names change all the time without a programmer getting involved in the decision.

Use the *readonly* keyword for public constant values.

Comment: I think with static properties which return a constant you get the best of both ways. The JITter will most likely inline them, so you get good performance, but the constant doesn't get embedded into the calling assembly.