# c# class for constants bindable in xaml as well as in code

Tags: c#, xaml

I would like to have a class with constant strings, like for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842590/static-constants-in-c-sharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/c-static-readonly-vs-const). But I would like to be able to bind to these values **in xaml as well as in code**, e.g.:

```
<Window x:Class="Ccompany.Product.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:lex="http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com"
        lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly="<-- would like to be able to insert the constant here -->"                
        >
```

Could you please also provide an example of how to bind the proposed 'constants class' solution in xaml as well?

*Note:* I tried different things before posting, tried to wrap the constant into a property but I was still unable to bind it in xaml.

Comment: `I tried different things before posting` Show exactly what you tried and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just this?:

```
{x:Static ns:TypeName.ConstValue}
```

This will work for constant values like the following:

```
public class TypeName
{
    public const int ConstValue = 5;
}
```

Comment: Constants.cs: `namespace Company.Product.Common.Constants { public class Constants2 { public const string DefaultAssembly = "value"; } }`. MainWindow.xaml: `<Window ...  xmlns:constants="clr-namespace:Company.Product.Common.Constants" lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly="{x:Static constants:Constants2.DefaultAssembly}" ...>` produces: The name "Constants2" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Company.Product.Common.Constants".

Comment: Today I created an empty (new) project, tried your solution and it worked. There must have been something wrong with the project in which I tried it before. I remember I tried to clean/rebuild even restart Visual Studio - without success. I'd like to apologize for my mistake. Your answer is actually a correct one. Thank you.