# Why can constants be implicitly converted while static readonly fields cannot?

Tags: c#, static, constants

Given the below code, I wonder why `referenceValue = ConstantInt;` is valid while `referenceValue = StaticInt;` fails to compile.

```
namespace Demo
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private const int ConstantInt = 42;
        private static readonly int StaticInt = 42;

        public void DemoMethod(ref uint referenceValue)
        {
            referenceValue = ConstantInt; // This compiles
            referenceValue = StaticInt; // This claims that the source type 'int' cannot be converted to 'unit' implicitly. 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/2512946/1132334

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Constants are replaced at compile time with their respective value. So from the compiler perspective this `referenceValue = ConstantInt;` is the same as this `referenceValue = 42`.

While `readonly` fields feel similar, they are not. Their value is not truly known at compile time. They are backed by a static field on the class. Their value can be computed, even modified from a static constructor, so the compiler can't check that the value is within the range of `uint` at compile time.

For example:

```
public class Class1
{
    private const int ConstantInt = 42;
    private static readonly int StaticInt = 42;

    static Class1()
    {
        StaticInt = -20;
    }

    public void DemoMethod(ref uint referenceValue)
    {
        referenceValue = StaticInt; // it's -20
    }
}
```

**Edit**

As pointed out in the comments not all assignments from constants to variables work, `long` constant to `int` variable does not work without an explicit cast. This behavior is the same based on the type of the constant, regardless   of whether it is a named constant or an inline constant:

```
private const long ConstantInt = 42;
// Both of these will cause an error:
referenceValue = ConstantInt; // can't be converted implicitly
referenceValue = 42L; // but neither can an inline long constant (the L makes it long)
```

Comment: *so from the compiler perspective this `referenceValue = ConstantInt;` is the same as this `referenceValue = 42;`* Not true, since `const long ConstantInt = 42` will error out. The *value* is not leading! The type still is. The thing is that the compiler can do some conversions, and some not. In that regard it goes further than what the runtime can do.

Comment: @PatrickHofman you are right, it is an oversimplification, I meant that the constant will actually get replaced with it's value in the IL, with regard to conversions, you are right, not any conversion will work but this is more dictated by the rules that would govern assignments anyway : `referenceValue = 20L` does not work ,  `referenceValue = 20u` works

Comment: Just to be clear, the rule is that an int constant can be converted to sbyte, byte, short, ushort, uint, or ulong if the value fits, and a long constant can be converted to ulong if it fits. Normally C# would not allow those conversions but it makes an exception for constants that are known to fit. But you can't put a long constant into an int even if it fits; that's likely to be a mistake so C# flags it as such.

Comment: *the compiler can't check that the value is within the range of uint at compile time.* well actually it cannot **always** check that value. It could check if there are such static constructors/computations and if none is there allow the assignment, and even if there were it could try to perform some static analysis to prove that... obviously this last analysis may not always work.

Answer (score 11):

Because constant fields are evaluated on compile time, while `readonly` fields are evaluated on run time. The interpreter in the compiler treats your integers differently than the runtime does.

The compiler recognizes the value and its type and it can do some basic conversion based on that, as it does in this case. Try and see what happens if you set `ConstantInt` to a negative number. The compiler will error out. The same is true when you change the type to `long` or `float`: there is no compiler conversion rule, so it errors out too.

Answer (score 2):

from the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly)

> The readonly keyword is different from the const keyword. A const field can only be initialized at the declaration of the field. A readonly field can be initialized either at the declaration or in a constructor. Therefore, **readonly fields can have different values depending on the constructor used. Also, while a const field is a compile-time constant, the readonly field can be used for runtime constants**
>
> as in this line: public static readonly uint l1 = (uint)DateTime.Now.Ticks;