# The constant cannot be marked static

Tags: c#

I am trying to declare a PI constant like this:

```
public static const double PI = Math.PI;
```

but why am I getting this error?

```
The constant 'Calendar.NewCalendar.PI' cannot be marked static
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408192/why-cant-i-have-public-static-const-string-s-stuff-in-my-class

Answer (score 218, accepted):

`const` implies `static` (you don't need an instance to reference the `const` value).

I want to also add this important point: When you link against (reference) an assembly with a `public const`, that value is **copied** into your assembly. So if the `const` value in the referenced assembly changes, your assembly will still have the originally compiled-in value.

If this behavior is *not* acceptable, then you should consider making the field a `public static readonly` field.

*Lib.dll, provided as binary:*

```
public class Foo {
    public const int HATS = 42;
    public static readonly int GLOVES = 33;
}
```

*App.exe, references Lib.dll:*

```
Foo.HATS    // This will always be 42 even if the value in Lib.dll changes,
            // unless App.exe is recompiled.

Foo.GLOVES  // This will always be the same as Foo.GLOVES in Lib.dll
```

---

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx):

> Don’t create a constant to represent information that you expect to change at any time. For example, don’t use a constant field to store the price of a service, a product version number, or the brand name of a company. These values can change over time, and because **compilers propagate constants**, other code compiled with your libraries will have to be recompiled to see the changes.

From [DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/readonly):

> DLLs. When you use a `const` field or declaration, the C# compiler actually embeds the `const` variable's value directly in the IL code. Therefore, it essentially erases the `const` as a separate entity.
>
> Caution:
>   If programs that depend on a `const` are not recompiled after the `const` value changes, they may break [*because they'll continue to use the previous value*].

Answer (score 15):

A constant is static by definition.

Comment: is this applied on` final ` in java too

Comment: @BasheerAL-MOMANI: No. A final is just unchangeable after the constructor call. Nothing more.

Answer (score 10):

You can't have static const. Try readonly instead of const or simply drop the "static" since "const" is implied static anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Constants cannot be replaced in the code during compilation, not runtime, so there's no requirement for static vs instance definitions.

Answer (score 3):

All constants declarations are implicitly static, and the C# specification states that the (redundant) inclusion of the static modifier is prohibited. I believe this is to avoid the confusion which could occur if a reader were to see two constants, one declared static and one not – they could easily assume that the difference in specification implied a difference in semantics. Having said that, there is no prohibition on redundantly specifying an access modifier which is also the default one, where there is a choice. For instance, a (concrete) method can be explicitly marked as private despite that being the default. The rule appears to be that where there is no choice (e.g. a method declaration in an interface) the redundant modifier is prohibited. Where there is a choice, it’s allowed.