# CIL - How do I use a public static literal field?

Tags: c#, mono, cil, ilasm

This might be a dumb question but I'm really curious if I can do this. I wrote the following sample program:

```
class Test1 {

    public const int b = 8;
    public static int z = 3;

    public static void Main(string[] args){
        const int q = 6;
        Console.WriteLine(q);
        Console.WriteLine(b);
        Console.WriteLine(z);

    }
}
```

Y compiled this using `mcs` and then I diassembled the generated exe with `monodis`. Obtained the following code:

```
.field public static literal  int32 b = int32(0x00000008)
.field  public static  int32 z

// method line 2
.method public static hidebysig 
       default void Main (string[] args)  cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2058
      .entrypoint
      // Code size 23 (0x17)
      .maxstack 8
      IL_0000:  ldc.i4.6 
      IL_0001:  call void class [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
      IL_0006:  ldc.i4.8 
      IL_0007:  call void class [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
      IL_000c:  ldsfld int32 Test.Test1::z
      IL_0011:  call void class [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
      IL_0016:  ret 
} // end of method Test1::Main
```

I want to use `ldsfld` to load the value of b. If I change IL_0006 to `ldsfld int32 Test.Test1::b`, it will assemble, but when I run the executable I obtain an excpetion:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in Test.Test1:Main 
(string[]): IL_0006: ldsfld    0x04000001


[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidProgramException: 
Invalid IL code in Test.Test1:Main (string[]): IL_0006: ldsfld    0x04000001
```

Is there any way to use the `static literal` instead of just using `ldc`?

Comment: This is the problem with `const` fields - they don't "exist" anywhere at runtime, except for where they are used.  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173119.aspx), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755685/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13150388/119527).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart If so, how did monodis reproduce the source code which declares `b`?

Comment: It's still embedded in the assembly. As it is `public`, other code may link against it, and use that literal.  I'm not terribly familiar with `const` at the IL level, but I believe what you're seeing is due to the implementation of `const` as described in those links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already have comments-as-answers from a C# perspective, but the CIL spec is more appropriate and rather explicit on it too:

> **I.8.6.1.2 Location signatures**
>
> The **literal constraint** promises that the value of the location is actually a fixed value of a built-in type. The value is specified as part of the constraint. Compilers are
> required to replace all references to the location with its value, and the VES therefore
> need not allocate space for the location. This constraint, while logically applicable to
> any location, shall only be placed on static fields of compound types. ***Fields that are
> so marked are not permitted to be referenced from CIL*** (they shall be in-lined to their
> constant value at compile time), but are available using reflection and tools that
> directly deal with the metadata.

So, no, there is no way at all to reference that field directly, and there isn't supposed to be.

Comment: Alright, so... I'm building a compiler and I'm currently generating CIL code. If I guarantee that the constant values shall not be reassigned, could I declare my constants without the literal value in order to make my code generation a little bit more comprehensible? Also, I will accept your answer, this is what I was trying to understand.

Comment: @EdwinA.GonzálezUrzua You could make it `initonly` (equivalent to C#'s `readonly`), if I understand you correctly.